# Is it possible to fire the oninput event for HTML5 input sliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a HTML5 input slider that I'm changing via JavaScript (in my example I'm changing it with a jquery UI slider, but it's possible it could also be changed due to other user input, e.g. click this button for 1x, 2x zoom, etc.)

The slider has the `oninput` event attached to it, so that when the user changes the slider value, it then updates the user interface.

The problem is, that changing the value via JavaScript doesn't fire the `oninput` event, I've tried doing `rangeInputRaw.oninput()` which apparently works for `textarea`'s but it just throws an error on the range input.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/qc03cumt/1/

(if you slider the jQuery UI slider, you'll see the top HTML slider changing, but the value for it doesn't update, if you slide the HTML slider however, the value does update)

For future reference, the HTML looks like this:

```
<h1>Range Slider</h1>

<form action="">
    <p>Range current value <span id="range-current-value">N/A</span></p>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input" id="range-input" />

    <p>Current value: <span id="currrent-value">N/A</span></p>
    <div class="slider" id="slider"></div>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript looks like this:

```
var currentValue = $("#currrent-value");
var htmlRange = $("#range-input");
var htmlRangeRaw = document.getElementById("range-input");

$("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        currentValue.html(ui.value);
        htmlRange.val(ui.value);
    }
});

var rangeInputRaw = document.getElementById("range-input");
var rangeInputOutput = document.getElementById("range-current-value");
rangeInputRaw.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    console.log("change");
    rangeInputOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
})
```

As stated, the example uses jQuery UI, but it's also feasible you'd want to change the range input value on other user interactions, e.g. changing another form value or clicking a button.

I can't change the event listener from `oninput` to `onchange` as it needs to update incrementally, not when the user has finished their interaction.

Comment: This is not a solution... but as a fix you could simply put a named function as event handler rather than anonymous and call that function. And I will check why this issue happens? and has any better solution?

Comment: Thanks Vinod, that is a potential solution, unfortunately though I'd have to modify an external JS library to make that work (which isn't ideal) so I'm keen to avoid that solution if at all possible.

Comment: If you don't mind changing addEventListener to onInput = function then check this http://jsfiddle.net/qc03cumt/3/

Comment: Nice one! It's interesting how they work slightly differently between using the old method and the `addEventListener` method. I guess this is even better in some ways as the support will be better for it.

Comment: @VinodKumar Feel free to add that as a full answer if you want, I'll happily accept it :)

Comment: Thanks! :) I just added a direct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind changing "addEventListener" to "onInput = function" then check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/qc03cumt/3/)

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        currentValue.html(ui.value);
        htmlRange.val(ui.value);
        htmlRange[0].onInput();
    }
});
....
rangeInputRaw.onInput = function(event) {
    console.log("change");
    rangeInputOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work with jQuery events:

```
$("#range-input").on("input", function(e) {
    console.log("change");
    rangeInputOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
});

...

htmlRange.val(66);
htmlRange.trigger("input");
```

UPDATE:

Here is the complete HTML page (without jQuery UI):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Range Slider</h1>

        <form action="">
            <p>Range current value <span id="range-current-value">N/A</span></p>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input" id="range-input" />

            <input type="button" id="change" value="Change">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var htmlRange = $("#range-input");

        $("#change").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            htmlRange.val(66);
            htmlRange.trigger("input");
        });
        var rangeInputOutput = document.getElementById("range-current-value");
        $("#range-input").on("input", function(e) {
            console.log("change");
            rangeInputOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think your answer is valid, at least I can't get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/n7jj3x2f/

Comment: @SeanDunwoody try with the complete page I just posted (adjust the jquery src to fit your environment)